# What websites biologists use to check what new plant or animal species have been discovered in the world?

Tags: zoology, botany, taxonomy, database

What are the databases or websites that biologists use to check what new plants or animals have been found in the world? The service should list the location of the discovery, time of discovery, image of the new species, the name of the discoverer and other vital information

Comment: “The service should list…”. Is this an invitation to tender?